# Degree of covering map

Tags: general-topology

For a given manifold $X$, is it true that for any $n\geq 1$, we can always find a covering map $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ of degree $n$?

Comment: No. I assume you mean connected covers. These exist iff the fundamental group has a subgroup of index $n$ and this need not be the case, e.g. the fundamental group might be trivial.

Comment: Yes, I just realize that this is a dumb question. As long as the fundamental group is finite, then there is no way to have degrees to be all integers. For example, the covering spaces for $RP^2$ can only have degree 1 or 2. Thx!

Comment: There are also infinite groups without proper subgroups of finite index, think of $({\mathbb Q},+)$ for instance.